# Doctrine update keeps changing my integers to varchars

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working on a Symfony 2.8 project which implements an OpenCart database. I have set up some mappings in order to be able to pull in customer / address / order details and so far it seems to be OK.

However, after I change something in my entites for a bespoke table, I try to --force update my database and I get the following errors:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]   An exception occurred
>   while executing 'ALTER TABLE oc73_customer CHANGE address_id
>   address_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL':   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1832 Cannot change column 'address_id': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'FK_   B25E4F72F5B7AF75'
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1832 Cannot change column 'address_id': used in a foreign key
>   constraint 'FK_   B25E4F72F5B7AF75'

It seems that my update is trying to change the address_id in oc73_customer to a VARCHAR after I change it to an INT in order to match the foreign keys. I check my Entity (Oc73Customer):

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address_id", type="integer")
*/
private $addressId;
```

In my oc73_address table, my Entity entry:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="address_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $addressId;
```

Which is also set as an integer - so why does my update keep attempting to change the address_id in my oc73_customer table to a VARCHAR? I cannot find anywhere in the code that it's stating that it should be?

If it's any help, here is my config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                schema_filter: ~^(?!oc73_simple_*)~
                mapping_types:
                  enum: string
   orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated - it seems like a real headache dealing with OpenCart databases with Doctrine and Symfony.

Thank you
Michael

Comment: The addresId shouldn't be a mapping field something like that?:
`/**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $address;`

Anyway, backing to topic, did you try drop your whole database (if you can of course) and create from begining

Comment: No, I can't really drop the database, but I think I may just have solved it - I believe it was a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - it turns out it was a cache issue. When I cleared my cache and deleted the directories, the database update worked and matched my stated column definitions.